# How to reference ${catalina.home} in logback using logback.groovy script

Tags: logging, groovy, logback, logback-groovy

I have recently switched to logback.groovy and trying to run my app but logging fails with error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: catalina for class: Script1
```

I suspect it's due to this part of my script :

```
def LOG_DIR = "${catalina.home}/logs/"

if(hostname =~/myhost|productionhostname/) {
    LOG_DIR = "/opt/tomcatinstances/myapp/logs/"
}
```

I have renamed that to `$catalina.home` but it didn't work either. Is there anything I am not doing right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat log directory can be obtained using below code

```
def TOMCAT_LOG_DIR = System.getenv()['CATALINA_BASE'] + "/logs"
```